# NSRangeException beyond bounds when inserting row into a tableview off screen iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, nsrangeexception

I'm having a problem with my Swift/iOS app when it comes to dealing with a UITableView using static cells.

My tableview has a couple of sections in it, which in turn each section has a couple of rows in it.  In my code, if you tap on one of the cells, it will dynamically insert another cell into the table.  For example, tapping on a row for date, will insert a data picker in a new cell, thus pushing the other row down the screen further.

On devices with larger screens this works just fine.  The table row gets inserted and everything works fine because even with the data picker inserted, all the rows still fit on the screen.  However, on a device with a smaller screen, if the inserted row pushes any of the rows below if off screen, and I try to scroll down to those rows, I get an NSRangeException, beyond bounds.  I can't seem to figure out how to handle telling the tableview that those rows do exist and allow me to scroll without crashing.

I can supply more information if this isn't enough.

Thanks!

[Updated with code]

// MARK: - Show/Hide Parent Airline Picker (Section 1, Row 0/1)

```
func showAirlineOperatedByAirlinePicker() {
    airlineOperatedByAirlinePickerVisible = true

    let indexPathAirlineOperatedByAirlineRow = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 1)
    let indexPathAirlineOperatedByAirlinePicker = NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 1)

    airlineOperatedByAirlineLabel.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPathAirlineOperatedByAirlinePicker], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPathAirlineOperatedByAirlineRow], withRowAnimation: .None)
    tableView.endUpdates()
}

func hideAirlineOperatedByAirlinePicker() {
    if airlineOperatedByAirlinePickerVisible {
        airlineOperatedByAirlinePickerVisible = false

        let indexPathAirlineOperatedByAirlineRow = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 1)
        let indexPathAirlineOperatedByAirlinePicker = NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 1)

        if airlineOperatedByAirlineLabel.text == "Operated By" {
            airlineOperatedByAirlineLabel.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
        } else {
            airlineOperatedByAirlineLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        }

        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPathAirlineOperatedByAirlineRow], withRowAnimation: .None)
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPathAirlineOperatedByAirlinePicker], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

// MARK: - Table View Data Source Functions

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 1 && airlineOperatedByAirlinePickerVisible {
        return airlineOperatedByAirlinePickerCell
    } else {
        return super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 1 && airlineOperatedByAirlinePickerVisible {
        return 3
    } else {
        return super.tableView(tableView, numberOfRowsInSection: section)
    }
}
```

// MARK: - Table View Delegate Functions

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    airlineCallSignTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    airlineIATATextField.resignFirstResponder()
    airlineICAOTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    airlineNameTextField.resignFirstResponder()

    if indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 0 {
        if !airlineOperatedByAirlinePickerVisible {
            showAirlineOperatedByAirlinePicker()
        } else {
            hideAirlineOperatedByAirlinePicker()
        }
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 1 && airlineOperatedByAirlinePickerVisible {
        return 217
    } else {
        return 44
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Int {
    var indexPath = indexPath
    if indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 1 {
        indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: indexPath.section)
    }
    return super.tableView(tableView, indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath? {
    if indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 0 && operatedByAirlineFetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects!.count > 0 {
        return indexPath
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

And finally, here is the error I'm getting.

2016-05-15 09:19:18.305 My Flight Log[10375:222325] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[**NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00aa9494 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02e81e02 objc_exception_throw + 50
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0097adee -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:] + 206
    3   UIKit                               0x0217a99d -[UITableViewDataSource tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 184
    4   UIKit                               0x01dc981d -[UITableViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 69
    5   My Flight Log                       0x000c8a4b _TFC13My_Flight_Log32AirlineModifyTableViewController9tableViewfTCSo11UITableView21cellForRowAtIndexPathCSo11NSIndexPath_CSo15UITableViewCell + 523
    6   My Flight Log                       0x000c8af9 _TToFC13My_Flight_Log32AirlineModifyTableViewController9tableViewfTCSo11UITableView21cellForRowAtIndexPathCSo11NSIndexPath_CSo15UITableViewCell + 89
    7   UIKit                               0x01ae7934 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 822
    8   UIKit                               0x01ae7a7d -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 90
    9   UIKit                               0x01ab7b32 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 3347
    10  UIKit                               0x01ad6416 __29-[UITableView layoutSubviews]_block_invoke + 52
    11  UIKit                               0x01af16cc -[UITableView _performWithCachedTraitCollection:] + 88
    12  UIKit                               0x01ad62eb -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 214
    13  UIKit                               0x01a2c3d4 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 810
    14  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02e96059 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
    15  QuartzCore                          0x07815096 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 144
    16  QuartzCore                          0x078088b6 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 388
    17  QuartzCore                          0x0780871a _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 26
    18  QuartzCore                          0x077faee7 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 317
    19  QuartzCore                          0x0782f847 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 561
    20  QuartzCore                          0x07830108 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 92
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x009bb75e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 30
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x009bb6be __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 398
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x009b103c __CFRunLoopRun + 1340
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x009b0846 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x009b065b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    26  GraphicsServices                    0x04cf3664 GSEventRunModal + 192
    27  GraphicsServices                    0x04cf34a1 GSEventRun + 104
    28  UIKit                               0x0195beb9 UIApplicationMain + 160
    29  My Flight Log                       0x000bebd1 main + 145
    30  libdyld.dylib                       0x03fb1a25 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: How are you inserting these new rows?, It would help people to help you if you showed some code ;)

Comment: You added a lot of code. Which line specifically is causing the error?

Comment: That's just it.  When the app crashes, it crashed back to the AppDelegate: (class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate) which isn't very helpful.

Comment: In the error index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]' . The system is attempting to get index 2 when there are only two items avaliable. Are you returning the correct value in your numberOfRowsInSection?

Comment: Hi, asking for a friend but did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: I re-engineered the code so that it's not trying to insert new rows.  Instead I constructed the table with all the rows already in the table, but hid some of them by setting their row height to 0 on load, and resizing the row when I need to display it.